# Crear subdocumentos unicos en mongoose

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Tengo los siguientes esquemas:

```
let CollaborationSchema = new Schema({

    role:{
        type: String,
        required: [true, "El rol es requerido"],
        default: "USER"
    },

    company: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Company',
        required: [true, "La compania es requerida"]
    },

    area:{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Subsudiary'
    },
    
    state:{
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }

})


let userSchema = new Schema({

    name:{
        type: String,
        unique: false,
        required: [true, 'El nombre es requerido']
    },

    collaborations: {
        type: [CollaborationSchema],
        required: [true, "La colaboracion es requerida"]
    }

})
```

Busco que el `User` tenga un array de empresas en las que colabora, por lo tanto, quiero restringir que las colaboraciones (dentro del array) sean únicas.

**Por ejemplo:**

```
db.users.insert({name:"Jose", [
   {role:"USER", company: 1, state: true},
   {role:"USER", company: 2, state: true},
   {role:"USER", company: 3, state: false}
]}) // ==> TRUE

db.users.insert({name:"Jose", [
   {role:"USER", company: 1, state: true},
   {role:"USER", company: 2, state: true},
   {role:"USER", company: 1, state: false}
]}) // ==> FALSE
```

Intente crear indices con mongoose de la siguiente forma:

```
userSchema.index({ email: 1, 'collaborations.company': 1 },{ unique: true });
```

Pero no funciono, intente definir los indices en el esquema `CollaborationSchema` de la siguiente forma:

```
CollaborationSchema.index({ company: 1 },{ unique: true });
```

Pero esto lo soluciona a medias, ya que mongo no me permite otro usuario colabore en la misma empresa que "Jose".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea crear una lista sin repeticiones de un campo específico en un documento de [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/).

Supongamos que tenemos la lista de colaboraciones de la siguiente forma:

```js
let collaborations = [
  {role:"USER", company: 1, state: true},
  {role:"USER", company: 2, state: true},
  {role:"USER", company: 1, state: false}
]
```

Como se aprecia, el primer y el tercer elemento se diferencian sólo por el campo `state`.

Lo que hay que tener en cuenta es qué valor puede ser repetido y qué valor no.

Si un usuario sólo puede colaborar en 1 compañía, entonces el campo único de cada documento de la lista debe ser `company`.

En tu pregunta queda claro que esta es la situación, sólo se puede añadir a la lista, colaboraciones en compañías diferentes. Un usuario no puede ser colaborador más de una vez en una misma compañía (independientemente del rol o del estado o cualquier otro campo).

Esto nos plantea un problema a la hora de actualizar los datos, ya que si bien MongoDB nos provee del operador [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/index.html) para añadir valores a una lista sin repetición, como ya vimos los objetos comparados de esta manera pueden ser diferentes en algún otro campo y por lo tanto son catalogados como diferentes.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Una solución es filtrar los documentos de colaboración según el valor de `company`, de esta forma no se podrán añadir elementos duplicados.

Sin embargo tenemos 2 escenarios:

1. Creación de documentos mediante `insert`
2. Actualización de documentos mediante `update`

**Creando documentos con `insert` en MongoDB o `save` en Mongoose**

Suponiendo que voy a crear un documento en MongoDB, no tenemos formas de asegurar durante la creación que la lista de colaboraciones no contenga elementos duplicados. Entonces debemos depurar los datos, antes de insertarlos, de alguna manera.

Para ello nos apoyaremos en el método [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) de Javascript.

Por ejemplo:

```
// teniendo el siguiente documento:
let user = {
  name: "JOSE",
  collaborations: [
    { role:"USER", company: 1, state: true },
    { role:"USER", company: 2, state: true },
    { role:"USER", company: 1, state: false}
  ]
}
// depuramos usando filter
let uniqueCollaborations = user.collaborations.filter((element, index) => {
  let notExist = true;
  for(let i = 0; i < index; i++) {
    if(user.collaborations[i].company === element.company) {
      notExist = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  return notExist;
});

// establecemos la lista filtrada
user.collaborations = uniqueCollaborations;

//ahora podemos insertar
db.users.insert(user);
```

Si deseamos hacer lo mismo con Mongoose, es sencillo ya que el código es básicamente el mismo, con la excepción que usaremos el método [`save()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save) de nuestro modelo:

```
User.save(user, callback);
```

**Mongoose: usando un función *middleware* en un *hook* de tipo `pre-save`**

Si deseamos *automatizar* la tarea de filtrar los documentos por el campo `company`, podemos delegar esta tarea a un [*middleware*](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) tipo [*pre*](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre) que se ejecutará siempre antes de salvar un documento creado a partir de nuestro modelo.

Nuestro esquema quedaría así:

```js
const UsuarioSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: 'El nombre es requerido'
  },
  collaborations: {
    type: [CollaborationSchema],
    required: 'La colaboración es requerida'
  }
});

//Creamos una función middleware tipo 'pre' para el evento 'save'
UsuarioSchema.pre('save', function() {
  //this se refiere al documento que estamos salvando en BD
  let uniqueCollaborations = this.collaborations.filter((element, index) => {
    let notExist = true;
    for(let i = 0; i < index; i++) {
      if(this.collaborations[i].company === element.company) {
        notExist = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    return notExist;
  });
  this.collaborations = uniqueCollaborations;
  // llamamos a next() para que se siga ejecutando el proceso de salvar el documento
  next();
});

// Ahora podemos instanciar el modelo
const Usuario = mongoose.model('Usuario', UsuarioSchema);

// definimos un documento
let user = new Usuario({
  name: 'JOSE',
  collaborations: [
    { role:"USER", company: 1, state: true },
    { role:"USER", company: 2, state: true },
    { role:"USER", company: 1, state: false}
  ]
});

// ya no es necesario filtrar el documento antes de salvarlo, ya que esto lo hará nuestro middleware

user.save()
.then(saved => {
  console.log(saved.collaborations);
  /* muestra la lista con sólo 2 elementos
  
  [
    { role:"USER", company: 1, state: true },
    { role:"USER", company: 2, state: true }
  ]
  
  */
})
.catch(errorHandler);
```

De esta forma, cada vez que se cree un documento usando el modelo de usuario, al salvar el mismo se ejecuta nuestra función *middleware* que se encarga de eliminar los registros duplicados sobre el campo `company`.

**Actualizando documentos con `update` en MongoDB y/o Mongoose**

Ahora nos enfrentamos a la situación de actualizar un documento existente. Para esto tenemos 2 escenarios:

1. Actualizar un elemento ya existente de la lista de colaboraciones. Por ejemplo si el usuario cambió el rol.
2. Agregar una nueva colaboración a la lista.

En ambos casos es una actualización sobre un documento de la colección de usuarios.

**Actualizar un elemento existente**

Atacar el primer caso es muy simple usando un filtro de `Array` ([*arrayFilters*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html#update-arrayfilters)) que funcionan igual tanto en MongoDB como en Mongoose.

Supongamos que vamos a modificar el campo `rol` del elemento de la lista cuyo campo `company` es 2, en el documento perteneciente al usuario identificado por el nombre 'JOSE' (aunque es más común usar el campo `_id` del documento).

Entonces, nuestro filtro de `Array` lo podemos escribir como:

```js
let filtroLista = [
  { 'element.company': 2 } // <- nótese que uso notación de punto encerrada entre comillas (pueden ser simples o dobles)
];
```

Estoy indicando con esto que voy a actualizar el elemento de la lista, cuyo campo `company` sea igual a 2.

Luego en la sentencia de actualización utilizo este filtro de la siguiente forma:

```js
db.users.update(
  { name: 'JOSE' },
  { $set: { 'collaborations.$[element].role': 'ADMIN' } }, // <- nótese que uso el nombre del elemento usado en el fitro: element
  { arrayFilters: filtroLista }
);
```

Si todo es correcto tendremos el mensaje:

> `WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })`

Y el documento podría verse así:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f4b8c5b9d730d7dbbd726fb"),
    "name" : "JOSE",
    "collaborations" : [
        {
            "role" : "USER",
            "company" : 1,
            "state" : true
        },
        {
            "role" : "ADMIN",
            "company" : 2,
            "state" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

Hemos cambiado correctamente el rol del usuario para la colaboración en la compañía identificada por el número 2.

En Mongoose el código es el mismo, excepto que lo aplicamos sobre el modelo de usuario:

```
User.update(
  { name: 'JOSE'},
  { $set: { 'collaborations.$[element].role': 'ADMIN' } },
  { arrayFilters: filtroLista },
  callback
);
```

**Insertar un nuevo elemento en la lista**

Para insertar un nuevo elemento en la lista vamos a recurrir al operador [`$nin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) y del operador [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/index.html) de MongoDB.

Supongamos que ahora nuestro usuario es colaborador en una compañía identificada por el número 3. Entonces podríamos usar el método [`updateOne()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/index.html) de la siguiente forma.

```js
// nuestra nueva colaboración
let collaboration: {
  role: 'USER',
  company: 3,
  state: false
};

db.users.updateOne(
  { name: 'JOSE', 'collaborations.company': { $nin: [collaboration.company] } },
  { $push: { collaborations: collaboration } },
  { upsert: false}
);
```

En este caso estoy actualizando un documento de la colección de usuarios cuyo campo `name` sea 'JOSE' y que no tenga ningún elemento en la lista de colaboraciones con el campo `company` igual al campo `company` de la colaboración que deseo insertar.

Si dicho filtro no devuelve ningún documento, significa que ya existe una colaboración en la compañía indicada en por el campo `company`, por lo tanto no se efectúa la operación de añadir la colaboración a la lista.

Por el contrario, si existe un documento en la colección de usuarios que en su lista de colaboraciones todas son diferentes del que deseo insertar, entonces se realizará la actualización.

Si todo va bien la salida se verá parecida a la siguiente:

> `{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 1, "modifiedCount" : 1 }`

Hemos usado el [parámetro `upsert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/index.html#parameters) explícitamente para indicarle a MongoDB que si no existe el documento (basado en el filtro usado) no se debe crear un nuevo documento. Si bien este parámetro es `false` por defecto, siempre es buena práctica mostrarlo en el código para que se entienda la intención al realizar la operación de actualización.

Nuevamente en el caso de Mongoose el código es igual excepto por el hecho que vamos a usar el método [`updateOne`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.updateOne) del modelo:

```
User.updateOne(
  { name: 'JOSE', 'collaborations.company': { $nin: [collaboration.company] } },
  { $push: { collaborations: collaboration } },
  { upsert: false},
  callback
);
```

Esta sería una forma de atacar el problema planteado en la pregunta.